# Conditional formatting in excel sheet

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I want to create an excel sheet using conditional format, where user can fill either cell A1(say) or A2(say). If he fill both then both cells becomes red.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, lack of example and desired output

Comment: Which cell becomes red? Is it all celle in the worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new conditional formatting rule and use the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option. You can use the formula:

```
 =CountA($A$1:$A$2)=2
```

When we use a formula to toggle conditional formatting, the formula has to return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` which is why we check if the result of this `CountA` formula returns `2`. If both cells `A1` and `A2` have any value then `CountA()` will return 2 and the result will be `TRUE`

[image]